# Confused about extern crate

Tags: rust, rust-crates

So I'm currently learning the Rust language on the official website and I'm in the middle of Chapter 12 where they want me to split some of my code from `src/main.rs` to `src/lib.rs`. At first I created a library crate named "minigrep" inside the binary crate:

- minigrep
- src

  - main.rs

but Rust couldn't find it. Next I tried moving it inside the src directory:

- src

  - minigrep
  - main.rs

Any help as to how Rust can detect an external crate?

Comment: I think the tutorial is expecting you to create a file called `lib.rs` right next to `main.rs`.

Comment: @PeterHall I went through this tutorial myself last week, and your comment is the answer.

Comment: This isn't anything to do with an external crate. This is just organising code within your project - no external crates involved.

Comment: @PeterHall It works thanks!